# Replace Specific Characters in String Vector When Found c++

Tags: c++, vector, replace, find

I have been having a bit of trouble with my find and replace function I can get it to replace all characters but I only want it to change the characters that match the banned words.

Here is my code so far

```
class getTextData
{   
private:
    string currentWord;
    vector<string> bannedWords;
    vector<string> textWords;
    int bannedWordCount;
    int numWords;
    char ch;
    int index[3];
    ifstream inFile ();
public:
    void GetBannedList(string fileName);
    void GetWordAmount(string fileName);
    void GetDocumentWords(string fileName);
    void FindBannedWords();
    void ReplaceWords(string fileOutput);
};

for(int i = 0; i <= numWords; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < bannedWordCount; j++)
    {
        if(string::npos != textWords[i].find(bannedWords[j]))
        {               
            textWords[i] = "***";
        }
    }
}
```

This just replaces with a fixed number of *** but I want it to replace the characters it finds with a * not the whole word.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at regular expressions(regex)?

Comment: Can you post declarations of `textWords` and `bannedWords`?

Comment: @hmjd I have amended my post to show the declaration.

Comment: @Tim I have just looked at regex but I am unsure as to how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numWords; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < bannedWordCount; j++)
    {
        size_t pos = textWords[i].find(bannedWords[j]
        if(string::npos != pos))
        {               
            textWords[i].replace(pos, bannedWords[j].length(), 
                                 bannedWords[j].length(), '*');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works but why is `bannedWords[j].length()` put in twice.

Comment: The first one is the length of the section to remove from the old string; the second is the number of '*'s to put in instead. (Dense) documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: No problem i have figured out what they do

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::string::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) to change a certain number of characters to several instances of the same character:

```
size_t idx = textWords[i].find(bannedWords[j]);
if(string::npos != idx)
{               
    textWords[i].replace(idx, 
                         bannedWords[j].length(),
                         bannedWords[j].length(),
                         '*');
}
```

Note, the terminating condition of the outer `for` loop looks suspicious:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numWords; i++)
```

if there are exactly `numWords` in `textWords` this will access one beyond the end of the `vector`. Consider using iterators or obtain the number of elements in the container you are indexing from the container itself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textWords.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bannedWords.size(); j++)
    {
    }
}
```

rather than duplicating the size information in other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use string::replace(), call it for each banned word and replace the text with a fixed string "*".
Syntax:

```
string& replace ( size_t pos1, size_t n1,   const char* s );
string& replace ( iterator i1, iterator i2, const char* s );
```